# Как отправить '-X POST' используя 'requests' в Python?

Tags: python, post

Я пытаюсь отправить запрос:

```
curl -u [staff_email]:[api_key] -F "case[attachments][0]=@/path/to/file1.ext" -F "case[attachments][1]=@/path/to/file2.ext" -F "case[content]=I need help" -F "case[subject]=I need help" -F "case[user_email]=user@domain.ru" -F "case[user_full_name]=FullName" -F "case[language_id]=2" -F "case[custom_fields][cf_44]=3" -X POST https://[domain].omnidesk.ru/api/cases.json
```

Используя библиотеку:

```
import requests
```

Какой правильный синтаксис использовать для (curl -X POST)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://curlconverter.com/

```
import requests

files = {
    'case[attachments][0]': open('/path/to/file1.ext', 'rb'),
    'case[attachments][1]': open('/path/to/file2.ext', 'rb'),
    'case[content]': (None, 'I need help'),
    'case[subject]': (None, 'I need help'),
    'case[user_email]': (None, 'user@domain.ru'),
    'case[user_full_name]': (None, 'FullName'),
    'case[language_id]': (None, '2'),
    'case[custom_fields][cf_44]': (None, '3'),
}

response = requests.post('https://[domain].omnidesk.ru/api/cases.json', files=files, auth=('[staff_email]', '[api_key]'))
```